# How to call var in return ()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can create an output using `return ()` two display two `const` containing numbers as values:

```
return (
   <div>
     <span>{const_one}</span> {const_two}
   </div>
)
```

If a random boolean `var statement = true` I want to output

```
return (
   <div>
     {const_one}
   </div>
)
```

Whenever I use `if ()` functions inside my `return ()` I get an error. How can I achieve this? I have tried to create a `const` checking the state and create another `const` that includes the output:

```
const statement = false;
// or
const statement = true;

let customOutput = '<span>{const_one}</span> {const_two}';

if (statement === true) customOutput = const_one;

return (
  <div>
    {customOutput}
  </div>
)
```

In this example the `const_one` or `const_two` tags are displayed as html text, instead of displaying their values (which are actually numbers):

`<span>{const_one}</span> {const_two}` instead of `<span>24</span> 36`.

How can I change the markup to display the `const` values inside of `{customOutput}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator for this:

```
return (
  <div>
    {statement
      ? const_one
      : <span><span>{const_one}</span> {const_two}</span>}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Is there a syntax error in your code? I got a an error while adopting it to my more complex code saying `parsing error: unexpected token`. Its written like this: `{pastDate
            ? data
            : <small>{item.teams && (item.teams.length)}/</small>{data}}`

Comment: It works when wrapping the whole line in a `span` like you did in your example. Why is that the case, as the whole statement is wrapped in a `div` and `const_one` does work without being wrapped?

Comment: That's a limitation of JSX. As you maybe know, JSX has to be compiled to `React.createElement` calls before the browser is able to execute it. If you remove the outer span, the resulting JavaScript code would contain an error. You can read a bit more about it here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

Comment: Also the Babel REPL helps to understand what processed JSX looks like: https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=const%20result%20%3D%20(%0A%20%20%3Cdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%7Bstatement%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3F%20const_one%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20%3Cspan%3E%3Cspan%3E%7Bconst_one%7D%3C%2Fspan%3E%20%7Bconst_two%7D%3C%2Fspan%3E%7D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A)%3B

Comment: Thanks a lot @amann for helping me understand this problem! I really appreciate it.